# Creating shorthands for commands in vscode terminal?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

It is possible to create git shorthands by defining `alias` in `.gitconfig`.

Is there a similar facility for all command line options. Say I am not interested in typing `npm run build && node index.js`, is there an option to define this with a short hand like `bld-run`.

I know this is theoretically possible but can't find clear documentation for this.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try to search how to create global alias for your shell (`PowerShell`/`Bash`/`cmd`/...).

Answer (score 0):

Thank u for the tip @alex. Posting the answer for future enthusiasts.

In mac os mojave, open `~/.bash_profile` in any text editor.

type as follows `alias c="clear"` and save the file.

Open new terminal and type `c` and your terminal will be all `clear`.

Same goes for other commands as well.